# Javascript change window.location and run async ajax get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I want to start an ajax loop with GET-requests to check statuses from my controller. Once the loop is started i want to start a file download by changing window.location.

However i get no console.logs from this code, why?

```
function getExcelIKT() {

        setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: getDownloadCSVForIKTStatusUrl,
                dataType: 'json',
                async: 'true',
                success: function (DownloadCSVForIKTStatus) {
                    console.log(DownloadCSVForIKTStatus);
                }
            });
        }, 3000);

        window.location = downloadExcelUrlIKT;

    }
```

Comment: I don't understand your logic. Once the loop is started you want to go to a different page, which will therefore immediately end the loop...? As for why you get console.logs, is the server responding with an error?

Comment: You change the location before the asynchronous response comes back, so your success handler isn't called.

Comment: could be that the GET doesn't end with a success ?

add an error handler like this     `error: (function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.status + ' - ' + ajaxOptions + ' - ' + thrownError); alert(xhr.responseText); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getExcelIKT() {

    setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: getDownloadCSVForIKTStatusUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            async: 'true',
            success: function (DownloadCSVForIKTStatus) {
                console.log(DownloadCSVForIKTStatus);
                if (false) { //change to some conditions
                    window.location = downloadExcelUrlIKT;
                }
            }
        });
    }, 3000);
}
```

Just change `if (false) {` to something `if (DownloadCSVForIKTStatus.success) {`

Why don't you see console.logs? Because `setInterval` and `$.ajax` functions are asynchronous. For example

```
setTimeout(function () {

   console.log(1);

   setTimeout(function () {
       console.log(2);
   },0);

   console.log(3);

},0);

console.log(4);
```

Result will be `4 1 3 2`. (I use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, which is also asynchronous even with timeout of 0 seconds)